# Passing arguments function with --argument or -a format

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, command-line, functions, command

Is it possible to pass arguments to Vimscript functions with the `--argument` or `-a` format, similar to arguments in the command line?

I am writing a command that submits a job in a remote machine. I have to pass the number of hours and the number of CPUs requested. Currently they are provided as positional parameters.

```
function! SubmitJob(hours,cpus)
    ...
endfunction
com -nargs=* Submit call SubmitJob(<f-args>)
```

For example, `:Submit 1 2` indicates 1 hour and 2 CPUs. Would it be possible to change the function and command above so that I can pass the arguments as `:Submit --hours 1 --cpus 2` or `:Submit -h 1 -c 2`? This way, it would be possible to change the parameter order, for example `:Submit --cpus 2 --hours 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you have to write such "option parser" yourself.

But quite probably there's no need to do this. Just re-write your function to accept dictionary argument. For example,

```
function! SubmitJob(opts) abort
    let l:opts = extend(copy(a:opts), #{hours: 1, cpus: 1}, 'keep')
    echo l:opts.hours l:opts.cpus
endfunction

:call SubmitJob(#{cpus: 2})
" hours=1 cpus=2
```

Comment: Thanks! Would it be possible to make a command for this function? Would the regular command syntax `com -nargs=* Submit call SubmitJob(<f-args>)` also work for functions with dictionary arguments?

Comment: @mgarort `command ... call SubmitJob(ParseAndBuildDictionary(<f-args>))`

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but I understand that `ParseAndBuildDictionary` is a custom function? I don't find it in `VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0`

Comment: @mgarort Yes, (almost) all builtin commands/functions start with a lower case letter. As I already said in my answer "you have to write option parser yourself".